# What is this piece of hardware called and how do I get more?

Tags: hardware

The circled piece slides onto and fits around the aluminum bar. The top of the piece contains a screw to tighten and hold onto the aluminum bar; the bottom contains a hole that fits a piece of twisted wire rope, from which a light hangs.

[image: Image of light-hanging system with relevant piece of hardware circled]

Comment: It looks fairly proprietary. I'd be surprised if you find that exact configuration (with the precise dimensions you need).

Comment: Where did you find the picture? If it was a manufacturer or retailer's website, that might be the best place to inquire.

Comment: I don't believe these are standard. If I were looking for something like this, I'd stop by my local lighting store with one and ask if they knew where to find any more.

Comment: The picture is from Amazon. I could get another of the whole kit for $25, so that may be the best answer. From poking around McMaster-Carr, it looks like it’s a variant of [these](https://www.mcmaster.com/products/wire-rope-end-fittings/eye-end-plug-lock-wire-rope-end-fittings-for-lifting/).

Comment: this may help ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=cable+lag&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images ... or this ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=cable+lights+parts&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: For what it's worth, generating a few more instances/versions of an odd plastic component is one of the better uses I've found for a 3D printer. Failing that, drop a note to the manufacturer and ask if you could order a few more?

Comment: @keshlam, unless that is a 3D **metal** printer ($$$), a plastic part could only serve for lost-wax casting. Far easier to fabricate from a a bit of rod stock: drill two holes, and turn down the end. 10 minutes work apiece.

Comment: If all it's supporting is a hanging lamp, plastic should be able to do the job.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, your cable is inserted into the hole in the top, coming out the bottom?  Then you insert the "thing" onto the rod through the hole in its side and use a set screw in the top to lock it in place on the rod?